# How to prevent a function create a new event window stack when resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, window-resize

I have a problem, I need to run a function when the browser width is less than **769px**.

I'm using `$(window).resize();` to detect when the browser changes wide.

When I adjust the size of the browser to, for example 750px, the function generates a new stack of the event, what I mean is, if now I click on the button, each event runs twice, and if I change the browser width again to say, 700px, now each of them is executed three times. For each change of width of the browser as long as it is less than 769px, a new event listener is "stacked".

How I can only update the event and not allow new one is created when resizing the browser?

To recreate the problem, follow these steps:

Here's a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Gonzalo2683/owgx1tge/) to a JSFiddle that reproduces my problem.

1. load the page
2. Click the button to see initial behavior
3. Change the size of the smallest browser 769px
4. Click another look at the buttons and see new behavior.
5. Resize the browser to a smaller width of 769px
6. Click on button and see behavior, the event now runs three times

Code:

```
var App = function() {

    var tempo, body;
    var Init = function() {
        body = $('body');
        $(window).resize(function() {
            clearTimeout(tempo);
            tempo = setTimeout(showonlyone, 500);
        });

        showonlyone();
    };

    var showonlyone = function() {
        console.log('Executing now !!!');
        var mobileClass = "small-device";
        var desktopClass = 'desktop-device';
        var windowWidth = getWindowWidth();

        if (windowWidth < 769) {
            body.addClass(mobileClass);
            body.removeClass(desktopClass);

            $('a[data-navtrigger]')
                .click(
                    function(e) {
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        var triggerTag = $(this);
                        var triggerName = $(this).attr(
                            "data-navtrigger");
                        var activo = true;
                        var activeClase = 'activoo';

                        console.log('triggerName: ' + triggerName);

                        $('a[data-navtrigger]')
                            .each(
                                function(index) {
                                    if ($(this).attr(
                                            "data-navtrigger") == triggerName) {
                                        if (!$(this).hasClass(
                                                activeClase)) {
                                            $(this)
                                                .addClass(
                                                    activeClase);
                                        } else {
                                            activo = false;
                                            $(this)
                                                .removeClass(
                                                    activeClase);
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        $(this).removeClass(
                                            activeClase);
                                    }
                                });

                        $('[data-navtarget]')
                            .each(
                                function(index) {
                                    console
                                        .log('triggerName Dentro: ' + triggerName);
                                    if ($(this).attr(
                                            "data-navtarget") == triggerName && activo) {
                                        $(this).slideDown(250);
                                    } else {
                                        $(this).slideUp(250);
                                    }
                                });
                    });
        } else if (windowWidth > 768) {
            body.removeClass(mobileClass);
            body.addClass(desktopClass);
            $('a[data-navtrigger]').unbind('click');
        }
    };

    var getWindowWidth = function() {
        return window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
    };

    return {
        init: function() {
            Init();
        }
    };

}();

$(document).ready(App.init);
```

Comment: Event handlers inside event handlers are a terrible idea.

Comment: What do you suggest as a solution? @adeneo

Answer (score 0):

What if you control these classes using CSS Media Queries? Then you can add the behaviors for the specified classes.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears because eventhandlers are stacked. Take for example:

```
$('<span>').appendTo($('body')).html("click me")
  .click(function() { console.log(1); })
  .click(function() { console.log(2); })
  .click(function() { console.log(3); }) // prints 1 2 3
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8f95m8cx/

You would have to either initialize the handlers once or to call them off.

```
$('<span>').appendTo($('body')).html("click me")
    .click(function() { console.log(1); })
    .click(function() { console.log(2); })
    .off("click")
    .click(function() { console.log(3); }) // prints 3
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8f95m8cx/1/